# is there a method for comparing an index in lists?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm trying to access the information of a list that I created. and it is something like a multidimensional list. but how do I access it to compare the data for a unit test. I tried it the following way:

```
List<CalculationResult> results = CheckStepSix();

        List<CalculationResult> filteredResults = filterCalculations(results);

        Console.WriteLine($"{filteredResults.Count} results");

if (filteredResults.SingleOrDefault().savingsGasPerYear == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
            Assert.Fail();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("success");
        }
```

if I run this I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one element'

as end result I want to check if the list item is equall to 1 and if so the test should fail. and since it is an list in the list i want to know how to access it.

Comment: This is still kind of unclear. It might help a little if you show us the code for `CalculationResult` but at the moment, it doesn't look like you have a "list in a list".

Comment: Do you expect more than one hit in filteredResults? If it should be exactly one then do an explicitly Assert on `filteredResults.Count` first. And then an Assert on `filteredResults.Single().savingsGasPerYear`. Currently it looks like you are trying to test on two problems at once in your test,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can reference the list by using `filteredResults[0].savingsGasPerYear == 1`
that way I can access any list in a list with variables attached

Comment: Oh were you asking how to access an item in a list by its index? This is called an XY problem. You didn't explain what you are trying to do but instead directed to an error that some piece of code is giving (that you thought was the way to solve a problem).

Comment: Just to clarify: If `filteredResults[0].savingsGasPerYear == 1` is legal code, you are accessing a _class member_ with `filteredResults[0].savingsGasPerYear`, a _list item_ (which is an instance of a class) with `filteredResults[0]` and a _list_ with `filteredResults`. Hence, you are not referencing a _list_ with `filteredResults[0].savingsGasPerYear == 1 `.

Answer (score 0):

You are implying that your list should have exactly 0 or 1 items with SingleOrDefault(). If that list have more items than 1 then it would cause an exception. It is what SingleOrDefault() is for. If it were FirstOrDefault() then the list might have many items but you would be asking for the first item. The item you are looking for might not be the first one then and still you may be looking for it. Then:

```
if ( filteredResults.Any( x => x.savingsGasPerYear == 1) )
```

is what you are looking for. It asks if ***any*** of the items in the list has one with savingsGasPerYear == 1.